# Retrofit parse result into different module object

Tags: json, object, get, retrofit, retrofit2

i've a simple GET request with Retrofit and the object response is a list of two different type of json object radomized, how can i parse this into the correct java module object?

This is my easy request:

```
@GET("/News")
Observable<ArrayList<?????????>> getNews(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization
);
```

and the json response should be:

```
[
{
    "id": ...,
    "titolo": ...,
    "contenuto": ...,
    "data": ...
},
{
    "id": ...,
    "titolo": ...,
    "contenuto": ...,
    "data": ...
},
{
    "id": ...,
    "oggetto": ...,
    "contenuto": ...,
},
{
    "id": ...,
    "titolo": ...,
    "contenuto": ...,
    "data": ...
},
{
    "id": ...,
    "oggetto": ...,
    "contenuto": ...,
},
{
    "id": ...,
    "oggetto": ...,
    "contenuto": ...,
}
]
```

with different object..

thanks!

Comment: Do these objects have a common parent class?

Comment: Actually not, they just extends Parcelable to Parcel the data..